# Display all pages in category if select option select all categories

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating a search form with codeigniter and on my select form for my **$categories** I have a select option called **Search All Categories**

I would like to know how can I make it so on my select form when I click on the select option Search All Categories and then press submit it will display all pages.

I can get category id by `$category_id = $this->input->post('category_search');` model function

Currenly I can only select one category at a time and press submit and will only display pages in that category.

**Model function for single category search:**

```
public function get_category_page_search_results() {

    // This input gets the category id selected.
    $category_id = $this->input->post('category_search'); 

    $this->db->from('page_to_category p2c', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('page p', 'p.page_id = p2c.page_id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->join('page_description pd', 'pd.page_id = p2c.page_id', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->where('p2c.category_id', $category_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Search Controller**

```
<?php

class Search extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['title'] = "Search";

        $search_filter = $this->input->get_post('search_filter');

        if (empty($search_filter)) {
            $data['search_criteria'] = "Search";
        } else {
            $data['search_criteria'] = "Search" .'-'. $this->input->get_post('search_filter');
        }

        $data['searched'] = $this->input->get_post('search_filter');

        $this->load->model('admin/tool/model_tool_image');

        $data['categories'] = array();
        $data['pages'] = array();

        $category_results = $this->get_all_categories_for_search();

        foreach ($category_results as $result) {
            $data['categories'][] = array(
                'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                'name' => $result['name']
            );
        }

        if(!empty($_POST['input-search-category'])) {

            $page_results = $this->get_category_page_search_results();

            foreach ($page_results as $page) {
                $data['pages'][] = array(
                    'page_id' => $page['page_id'],
                    'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($page['image'], 100, 100),
                    'name' => $page['name'],
                    'description' => $page['description']
                );
            }
        }

        if (!empty($_POST['search'])) {

            $results2 = $this->get_search_results();

            foreach ($results2 as $result) {
                $data['pages'][] = array(
                    'page_id' => $result['page_id'],
                    'image' => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], 100, 100),
                    'name' => $result['name'],
                    'description' => $result['description']
                );
            }
        }       

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('search_filter', '');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category_search', '');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

            $data['column_left'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/column_left/index');
            $data['column_right'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/column_right/index');
            $data['content_top'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/content_top/index');
            $data['content_bottom'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/content_bottom/index');
            $data['footer'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/footer/index');
            $data['header'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/header/index');  
            $this->load->view('theme/default/template/pages/search_view', $data);

        } else {

            $data['column_left'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/column_left/index');
            $data['column_right'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/column_right/index');
            $data['content_top'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/content_top/index');
            $data['content_bottom'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/content_bottom/index');
            $data['footer'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/footer/index');
            $data['header'] = Modules::run('catalog/common/header/index');  
            $this->load->view('theme/default/template/pages/search_view', $data);
        }
    }

    // @To do create search Model

    public function get_search_results() {
        $match = $this->input->post('search_filter');
        $this->db->from('page', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('page_description', 'page_description.page_id = page.page_id');
        $this->db->like('name', $match);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_all_categories_for_search() {
        $this->db->from('category', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('category_description', 'category_description.category_id = category.category_id', 'LEFT');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    public function get_category_page_search_results() {
        $category_id = $this->input->post('category_search');
        $this->db->from('page_to_category p2c', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('page p', 'p.page_id = p2c.page_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->join('page_description pd', 'pd.page_id = p2c.page_id', 'LEFT');
        $this->db->where('p2c.category_id', $category_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

**Search View**

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $column_left; ?>
        <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
        <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
        <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
        <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>">
            <?php echo $content_top; ?>
            <form action="<?php echo base_url('pages/search');?>" method="post" role="search" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1><?php echo $search_criteria;?></h1>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Search For Page</label>
                        <input type="text" name="search_filter" placeholder="Search For Page" value="" class="form-control"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Search By Category</label>
                        <select name="category_search" class="form-control">
                            <?php if ($categories) { ?>
                            <option value="">Search All Categories</option>
                            <?php foreach($categories as $category) {?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $category['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $category['name'];?></option>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <option>No Categories Created</option>
                            <?php }?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="input-search-category" value="Category Search" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <div class="row">
                <?php if ($pages) {?>
                <?php foreach ($pages as $page) {?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <a href=""><img src="<?php echo $page['image'];?>"></a>
                            <div class="caption">
                            <h3><?php echo $page['name']; ?></h3>
                            <p><?php echo $page['description']; ?></p>
                            <p>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read More</a>      
                            </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php }?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="jumbotron">
                          <h2>Pages meeting the search criteria</h2>
                          <p>You have not entered the search fieild yet or there was no result found</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php }?>
            </div>
            <?php echo $content_bottom; ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $column_right; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Snap Shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($category_id > 0){
    $this->db->where('p2c.category_id', $category_id);
}
```

Shouldn't that do it?